# Ridiculously large velocity: free fall, Stokes

Tags: gravity, friction, free-fall

According to free fall by Stokes law the terminal velocity is given by:

$$ v_T  = g\cdot\dfrac{m}{6\cdot r\cdot\pi\cdot \eta}$$ If you're talking about a chutist and use for air as viscosity $\eta = 17,1\cdot10^{-6} \,\mathrm{Pa\,s}$ u'll get...

$$v_T = 9.81\cdot \dfrac{60\,\mathrm{Kg}}{6\cdot\pi\cdot1\,\mathrm{m}\cdot17,1\cdot10^{-6} \,\mathrm{Pa\,s}} \approx1,8\cdot 10^{6}\,\frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$$ what's obviously way too much.

Was this the deal? Showing Stokes law is totally inappropriate for free fall?

Comment: My guess is that the Stokes law formula only applies to laminar flow (low Reynolds numbers) in a very viscous fluid.  Such conditions definitely do NOT apply to a sky diver.

Comment: [Stokes flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow)